# Не работает Telegram Бот

Tags: javascript, telegram

Не отправляет данные в Telegram, до этого грешил на API

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');
const axios = require ('axios');

const bot = new Telegraf('6648621180:AAHCQocIasatJUiOgHV6qsLh6AQu_BItbjo');

bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('send me ur geolocation'));

bot.on('message', async (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.message);
    if (ctx.message.location) {
        const weatherAPIUrl = `"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid=317bb621238efc6011949771e08baac0"`;   // const weatherAPIUrl = `https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${c
        const response = await axios.get(weatherAPIUrl);
        ctx.reply(`${response.data.name}: ${response.data.weather[0].main} ${response.data.main.temp} °C`);
    }
});

bot.launch();
```

Но выдаёт такую ошибку

```
errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 80
```

Comment: За токен всем сообществом очень благодарны, добро пожаловать на ruSO!

Comment: Я не уверен, но возможно проблема в ` кавычках. Так как получается, что у вас в ссылке участвуют две пары кавычек. Попробуйте от одной из них избавиться, оставив либо ` либо "

const weatherAPIUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid=317bb621238efc6011949771e08baac0";

Что-то вроде такого будет правильным